# Android Java ListView retrieve the list from Firebase database but display empty TextViews and Images

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an argent problem I can create the list view items from a Firebase real time database but the content of it is empty views all the text views and images have no data, I'm starting my way in firebase and new to all of this I did follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEmq1B1gveM&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hj6SDHf_YybDeVhUT9MXaj1&index=2

and i did exactly like it but the video tutorial shows a working list while my list is empty views, this is my code:

**Album.java:**

```
package com.emadzedan.michealjacksonnoads.michealjacksonnoads;

public class Album{
private String thumbAndID;
private String albumName;
private String numberOfSongs;
private String albumYear;

public Album() {
}

public Album(String thumbAndID, String albumName, String numberOfSongs, String albumYear) {
    this.thumbAndID = thumbAndID;
    this.albumName = albumName;
    this.numberOfSongs = numberOfSongs;
    this.albumYear = albumYear;
}

public String getThumbAndID() {
    return thumbAndID;
}

public void setThumbAndID(String thumbAndID) {
    this.thumbAndID = thumbAndID;
}

public String getAlbumName() {
    return albumName;
}

public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {
    this.albumName = albumName;
}

public String getNumberOfSongs() {
    return numberOfSongs;
}

public void setNumberOfSongs(String numberOfSongs) {
    this.numberOfSongs = numberOfSongs;
}

public String getAlbumYear() {
    return albumYear;
}

public void setAlbumYear(String albumYear) {
    this.albumYear = albumYear;
}
}
```

**AlbumsListAdapter.Java**

```
package com.emadzedan.michealjacksonnoads.michealjacksonnoads;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class AlbumsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Album> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Album> albums;

ImageView albumThumb;
TextView albumName;
TextView numberOfSongsText;
TextView numberOfSongs;
TextView albumYear;
TextView hiddenThumbORID;

public AlbumsListAdapter(Context context, List<Album> albums) {
    super(context, R.layout.albums_list_row, albums);
    this.context = context;
    this.albums = albums;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.albums_list_row, null, true);

    Album album = albums.get(position);

    //the new code it is not nessacery to cast fields
    albumThumb = view.findViewById(R.id.albumThumb);
    albumName = view.findViewById(R.id.albumName);
    numberOfSongsText = view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfSongsText);
    numberOfSongs = view.findViewById(R.id.numberOfSongs);
    albumYear = view.findViewById(R.id.albumYear);
    hiddenThumbORID = view.findViewById(R.id.hiddenThumbORID);

    Picasso.with(context).load("http://emadzedan.com/musiclibraryandroid_karaokebeta7/bandsimages/" + album.getThumbAndID() + ".png").into(albumThumb);
    albumName.setText(album.getAlbumName());
    numberOfSongs.setText(album.getNumberOfSongs());
    albumYear.setText(album.getAlbumYear());
    hiddenThumbORID.setText(album.getThumbAndID());


    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        //Second
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark2);
        albumThumb.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        albumYear.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        albumName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        numberOfSongsText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        numberOfSongs.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    } else {
        //First
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        albumThumb.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark2);
        albumYear.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        albumName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        numberOfSongsText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        numberOfSongs.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    return view;
}


}
```

**AlbumsContainerFragment.Java**

```
package com.emadzedan.michealjacksonnoads.michealjacksonnoads;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class AlbumsContainerFragment extends Fragment {
SharedPreferences prefs;

ImageView bandImageImageView;

SongsListFragment songsListFragment;

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference rootReference;

List<Album> albums;
ListView albumsListView;
AlbumsListAdapter adapter;

public AlbumsContainerFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albums_container, container, false);


    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int pixels = (int) (200 * scale + 0.5f);


    prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("SelectedItemsPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getContext().getSharedPreferences("SelectedItemsPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    int minNumberOfCovers = 1;
    int maxNumberOfCovers = 10;

    Random r = new Random();
    int coverNumberSelected = r.nextInt(maxNumberOfCovers - minNumberOfCovers + 1) + minNumberOfCovers;

    editor.putString("image", prefs.getString("bandname" + coverNumberSelected, "michaeljackson" + coverNumberSelected) + ".jpg");
    editor.putString("id", prefs.getString("bandname", "michaeljackson"));
    editor.apply();

    assert ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()) != null;
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    bandImageImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bandImageImageView);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load("http://emadzedan.com/musiclibraryandroid_karaokebeta7/bandsimages/" + prefs.getString("image", "michaeljackson1.jpg")).into(bandImageImageView);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("");
    rootReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("album");
    albumsListView = view.findViewById(R.id.albumsListView);
    albums = new ArrayList<Album>();

    songsListFragment = new SongsListFragment();

    //This is only because listview is inside scrollview
    int NumberOfAlbums = 29;
    int RowHeight = 106;
    albumsListView.getLayoutParams().height = Math.round(NumberOfAlbums * convertDpToPixel(RowHeight, getContext()));
    albumsListView.setFocusable(false);
    //===================================================

    return view;
}

public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return px;
}

public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dp;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //Fire base List===================================================
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot albumSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Album album = albumSnapshot.getValue(Album.class);
                albums.add(album);
            }

            adapter = new AlbumsListAdapter(getContext(), albums);
            albumsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            albumsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getContext().getSharedPreferences("SelectedItemsPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    //editor.putString("albumThumb", rootReference.child("album").child("" + position ).toString());
                    //editor.putString("albumName",rootReference.child("album").child("" + position ).orderByChild("name").toString());
                    editor.apply();

                    DrawerBaseActivity.backButtonTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    DrawerBaseActivity.CurrentFragment = "SongsList";
                    //DrawerBaseActivity.titleTextView.setText(rootReference.child("album").child("" + position ).orderByChild("name").toString());
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, songsListFragment).addToBackStack("SongsList").commit();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    rootReference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    //Query query = rootReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo("1");
    //query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    //End Of Fire base 
List===================================================
}
}
```

**Sample JSON:**
        {
        "album":     {

```
        "1": {
        "id":"1",
        "year": "1969 (The Jackson 5)",
        "name": "Diana Ross Presents The Jackson 5",
        "numberofsongs": "12"
    },

    "2": {
        "id":"2",
        "year": "1970 (The Jackson 5)",
        "name": "ABC",
        "numberofsongs": "12"
    }
}
}
```

I checked the IDs and Usually I do copy and paste so no typo errors, and the app dose not crash or show errors only empty views in the list view, please help me I have been 2 days working on it and with no result working!!!

Comment: I think the problem is that I missed something while using fragment as the tutorials is using activity

Comment: Make sure you are passing non empty albums to the **AlbumsListAdapter**

Comment: how could I do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your constructor argument names should match your Firebase db keys. Modify your Album class constructor like this.

```
public Album(String id, String name, String numberofsongs, String year) {
    this.thumbAndID = id;
    this.albumName = name;
    this.numberOfSongs = numberofsongs;
    this.albumYear = year;
}
```

Comment: I made this answer the correct answer but it is not quite the exact solution I must also rename all the (this.fieldnames) also

Comment: In that case keep your code as is, and modify your Firebase DB structure to match your variable names like below -
"1": {
        "thumbAndID":"1",
        "albumYear": "1969 (The Jackson 5)",
        "albumName": "Diana Ross Presents The Jackson 5",
        "numberOfSongs": "12"
    },

Comment: the json is big I just renamed the fields and it worked thanks a lot

Comment: Great. Even I had wasted my 2 days for this silly issue that no one mentions in any of their tutorial

Comment: @AnirbanRoy Changing the name of the arguments in the constructor will not help the OP solve this problem at all. Actually the way the OP has declared the constructor is very correct. Please check my answer to see how can be this problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that the name of the fields in your `Album` class are different than the name of the properties in your database. You have in your `Album` class a field named `thumbAndID` but in your database I see it as `id` and it is not correct. The names must match. There are two ways in which you can solve this problem.

The first one would be to remove the current data and add it again using the correct names. So you should have for your field id, the same name `thumbAndID` also in the database. This solution will work only if you are in testing phase.

The second approach, which is a more elegant one in my opinion, is to use `annotations`. Because I see that you are using private fields and public getters, you should use the [PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) annotation only in front of the getter. So your `Album` class should look like this:

```
public class Album{
    private String thumbAndID;
    private String albumName;
    private String numberOfSongs;
    private String albumYear;

    public Album() {}

    public Album(String thumbAndID, String albumName, String numberOfSongs, String albumYear) {
        this.thumbAndID = thumbAndID;
        this.albumName = albumName;
        this.numberOfSongs = numberOfSongs;
        this.albumYear = albumYear;
    }

    @PropertyName("id")
    public String getThumbAndID() {
        return thumbAndID;
    }

    public void setThumbAndID(String thumbAndID) {
        this.thumbAndID = thumbAndID;
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public String getAlbumName() {
        return albumName;
    }

    public void setAlbumName(String albumName) {
        this.albumName = albumName;
    }

    @PropertyName("numberofsongs")
    public String getNumberOfSongs() {
        return numberOfSongs;
    }

    public void setNumberOfSongs(String numberOfSongs) {
        this.numberOfSongs = numberOfSongs;
    }

    @PropertyName("year")
    public String getAlbumYear() {
        return albumYear;
    }

    public void setAlbumYear(String albumYear) {
        this.albumYear = albumYear;
    }
}
```

If you intend to use this solution, there is nothing else that you need to change in the database.